# Heroku Build Failure for Discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, heroku, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I have been coding a bot using discord.js, visual studio code, and node.js, and I have been trying to host it on Heroku. However, the log in my Heroku project claim that my build is failing, and it is giving the following message when I view the build log of the failure:

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > @discordjs/opus@0.5.0 install /tmp/build_0229f43f/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.5.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.5.0 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.q9Do7/_logs/2021-04-19T19_49_08_993Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Also, the more recent changes that I have made to my bot, like adding aliases to commands and changing the ping of my announce command, don't apply when I run the bot off of Heroku, but do work when I run the bot locally, and I think that the build failure may be the reason behind this. I may be wrong, but I am still relatively new to coding Discord bots. How can I fix the build failure?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for a solution to this problem all day.
I finally found it:
While hosting your bot on heroku you can use "[discord-music-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-music-player)" instead of @discordjs/opus or opusscript. **Tell me if it worked for you!**

Answer (score 0):

@discordjs/opus is not allowed on Heroku afaik.

Use opusscript instead if you *really* need to use music.

But as devs mentioned, @discordjs/opus is much better peformance wise so I recommend searching for another hosting solution if you want the audio streaming functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

`Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)` you need to hide your `node_modules` using `.gitignore` in your folder project